# Manually arrange product placement in cartthrob

Tags: sort, product

I am wondering if there is a way to make certain items appear first within a category, regardless of default item order?

I would like particular items, buried within several pages because item order defaults to alphabetical, to appear first.  Is this possible?

Comment: Could you please post your code snippet that you're using for displaying the products? I have some ideas, but it'd be easier to answer if I could see what you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the in-built 'sticky' option for an entry. All your sticky entries will appear first, regardless of your other orderby parameter values.

More information on the EE docs: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/publish.html#make-entry-sticky

Comment: Thanks!  This worked.  Its not a long term solution, as it isn't a sequential site wide.  but it moved a product that was buried 15 pages deep to the number one position within its category.  So thats great!  I can now "feature" or promote a dozen or so items per category.